# Using JQuery Waypoints to play a video when it is scrolled to

Tags: jquery-waypoints

I'm trying to play an HTML5 video when the user scrolls to it using the waypoints plugin for jQuery.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { videoSetup(); });
function videoSetup() {

    var video = $("#video");

    video.waypoint(function(direction) {
        video.get(0).play();
    });   

}
```

Put when the video is scrolled to nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

HTML markup would look like:

```
<div class="video-test">
  <video id="video1" width="960">
    <source src="video-folder/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
  </video>
</div>
```

Then your javascript to load the video at the `video-test` container waypoint would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
      var myVideo=document.getElementById("video1");

      $('.video-test').waypoint(function() {                
        myVideo.play(); 
        }, {
              offset: '50%',  // middle of the page
              triggerOnce: true // just my preference...
      });
});
```